# Extract error description from Jenkin console output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Is there any way to extract only error description from a Jenkins Console output to send the same via Email notification??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What kind of jobs are you using ? Pipeline ? Freestyle ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a scripted pipeline, you can use a try catch block to assign the error message to a variable. Then pass this to an email plugin as required (see body field in mail step)

For example:

```
try {
    sh 'might fail'
} catch (err) {
    def errorMessage = err
}
step([$class: 'mail', body: "Failed due to: ${errorMessage}", to: 'admin@somewhere' ])
```

Otherwise, if you are using a declarative pipeline, you can still use the scripted syntax by wrapping it all in a script block like this:

```
script {
    try {
        sh 'might fail'
    } catch (err) {
        def errorMessage = err
    }
    step([$class: 'mail', body: "Failed due to: ${errorMessage}", to: 'admin@somewhere' 
    ])
}
```